# In Visual Basic 6.0, how do I move to a specific line?

Tags: vb6

In Notepad, under the *Edit* menu there is the Goto button to move to a specific line. I have tried to do coding for this in Visual Basic 6.0, but it does not work. The code is as shown below

```
Private sub goto_click()
    Dim s As String
    s = InputBox("Enter line number")
    If IsNumeric(s) = True Then
        RichTextBox1.SelStart = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromChar(s - 1)
        RichTextBox1.Move (s)
        RichTextBox1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been ages and I don't have VB6 on my systems anymore.  I've cobbled this together from bits all over the net.  Hopefully it actually works...I can't test it:

```
Private Const EM_LINEINDEX = &HBB 

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Any, ByVal LParam As Any) As Long

Private Sub goto_click()
    Dim s As String
    s = InputBox("Enter Line Number")
    If IsNumeric(s) Then
        Dim index As Long 
        index = SendMessage(RichTextBox1.hWnd, EM_LINEINDEX, CLng(s) - 1, 0)
        RichTextBox1.SelStart = index
        RichTextBox1.SetFocus
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: no it does not work it give compile error in 1st line as constant fixed length string and declare statement not allowed as public member of object module. i make it private but again it give error as type mismatch in private sub goto_click

Comment: You may need to change those two `Public`s to `Private`.

Comment: no it does not work it give compile error in 1st line as constant fixed length string and declare statement not allowed as public member of object module. i make it private but again it give error as type mismatch in private sub goto_click

Comment: Which line gave you a type mismatch?...I can't see your screen.

Comment: at private sub goto_click()

Comment: The API declaration was missing a line continuation underscore on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

I test this code and it works fine.

```
Private Const EM_LINEINDEX = &HBB

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (
    ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, LParam As Any) As Long

Private Sub goto_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = InputBox("Enter Line Number")
    If IsNumeric(s) Then
        Dim index As Long
        index = SendMessage(RichTextBox1.hWnd, EM_LINEINDEX, CLng(s) - 1, 0)
        RichTextBox1.SelStart = index
        RichTextBox1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```